# Adding Hourly Gaps into a Frequency Table

Tags: r

I am trying to create two frequency tables, one that is daily, and one that is hourly. I am able to get the daily values fairly easily.

```
C<-Data
C$Data<-format(C$Data, "%m/%d/%Y")
Freq_Day<- C %>% group_by(Data) %>% summarise(frequency = n())
```

However when I try to get the hourly frequency by doing the following

```
B<-Data
B$Data<-format(B$Data,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
Freq_HRLY<-B %>% group_by(Data) %>% summarise(frequency = n())
```

It omits hours that simply did not occur in the data set. Thus it returns a column that is less than (# of Days) *24. How would I go about getting a column of dates in one hour increments with their corresponding frequency, in a way that if there is no occurrence in "Data' it just has a value of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `tidyr::complete` to fill in the missing hours on the `Freq_HRLY` data which is already calculated by creating a sequence of hourly interval between `min` and `max` `Data`.

```
library(dplyr)

Freq_HRLY %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Data = as.POSIXct(Data, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Data = seq(min(Data), max(Data), by = "1 hour"), 
         fill = list(frequency = 0))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, when I tried that it did not add values to Freq_HRLY, it just printed  # A tibble: 10,468 x 2
   Data                frequency
   <dttm>                  <dbl>
 1 2012-10-21 20:00:00         5
 2 2012-10-21 21:00:00         0
 3 2012-10-21 22:00:00         4
 4 2012-10-21 23:00:00         0
 5 2012-10-22 00:00:00         0
 6 2012-10-22 01:00:00         0
 7 2012-10-22 02:00:00         0
 8 2012-10-22 03:00:00         1
 9 2012-10-22 04:00:00         0
10 2012-10-22 05:00:00         1
# … with 10,458 more rows

Comment: @ThomasShort Please assign the data to an object. `Freq_new_HRLY <- Freq_HRLY %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Data = as.POSIXct(Data, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Data = seq(min(Data), max(Data), by = "1 hour"), 
         fill = list(frequency = 0))` and then check `Freq_new_HRLY`